# FFMPEG: Why MKV video converted to MP4 only plays on VLC Media Player?

Tags: windows-10, ffmpeg, vlc-media-player, mp4, matroska

I have a video in MKV format that I wanted to convert to MP4, so I used ffmpeg to convert it. The command I used was pretty simple:

```
ffmpeg -i <path_and_name_of_file>.mkv <path_and_name_of_file>.mp4
```

I don't really know how to use ffmpeg and since this is probably the only time I plan to use it I looked up how to do it online and it said I can just use that simple command if all I'm doing is changing the file format.
So I did that, and it did the process like normal (it took about 10 hours because it's a 1080p 3+ hours video) but when I tried playing the file it didn't work. I tried Movies & TV and Windows Media Player and they both open the file and show how long it is, but when I hit play nothing happens, not even an error message. But it did play when opening it with VLC Media Player or Chrome.
The problem is, both M&T and WMP play the original MKV file just fine, so I must have done something wrong with ffmpeg. Is it that I have to add more stuff to the command or something?

Comment: The difference might be that VLC comes with its own codecs, but the others use the installed system codecs. You might try installing some good codec pack. My own favorite is the [K-Lite Codec Pack](https://codecguide.com/download_kl.htm).

Comment: What was the original audio/video codec of the MKV file according to `ffprobe`, and what is the format of the new MP4?